# freecad window gets transparent

Tags: command-line, 18.04, transparency, cad, free-software

Recently, my **freecad** encountered with a strange problem of being transparent. When I open it, there is no problem ([image](https://pasteboard.co/IOhsgzv.png)). But when I select to go to a specific workplace, say **part**, the window gets transparent, so that my desktop is visible on freecad backside([This](https://pasteboard.co/IOhsKd3.png) is my desktop and [this](https://pasteboard.co/IOht2UD.png) is freecad window).
I have removed and re-installed it but the problem persists. I also have to mention it is not a matter of opacity that can be controlled from teminal by something like: `sh -c 'xprop...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem. It was related to **ANSYS** installation. It was noticed that *if you have transparency issues in CFX pre/post or turbogrid, add **this** to* `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
export XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1
```

It solved the problem both in ANSYS and freeCad.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in FreeCAD on Manjaro Linux with XFCE. Solution was almost identical. Add `export XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS=1` to `~/profile`. Now every time I select text in Firefox (as I am writing this) it crashes. Thank you for the help though.